# How to initialize Providers passing component attributes as parameter in angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a component named `workspace` which should provide a service named `DbService`.
This service is meant to be used by the child components of `workspace`.
`DbService` has a parameter `path`.

I want to be able to initialize my components as follows:

```html
<workspace db="/a/b/c"></workspace>
<workspace db="/d/e/f"></workspace>
```

and make sure that each `DbService` providers that are initialized within workspaces have access to the db attribute value in their constructor.
Also dbService is asynchronously initialised. Ideally children component should be initialized after dbService is fully initialized.

I have tried many different things but no success so far.

What is the recommended way to initialize a `Provider` asynchronously with parameters coming from component attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't something that can be treated by DI alone, because attributes aren't available at the time when a service is instantiated.

The workaround is

```
class DbServiceContainer {
  instance: DbService;
}

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [DbServiceContainer]
})
class WorkspaceComponent {
  constructor(@Attribute('db') db, dbServiceContainer: DbServiceContainer) {
    dbServiceContainer.instance = new DbService(db);
  }
}

@Component({ ... })
class WorkspaceChildComponent {
  dbService: DbService;

  constructor(dbServiceContainer: DbServiceContainer) {
    this.dbService = dbServiceContainer.instance;
  }
}
```

Comment: new DbService(db); doesn't guarantee immediate availability therefore cannot be used by the children component at the desired time.

Comment: What is 'desired time'? It can be used in children component constructor, as the example shows. The question doesn't explain why there can be a problem with this approach. If dbService is initialized asynchronously then it should return a promise or observable.

Comment: by 'desired time' I I mean children can get a reference to it but still they should now if they can start using it or now. If dbService provides an observable how can I guarantee that it will notify only once all the children components are initialized?

Comment: A promise/observable solves that, I don't see any problem with it. The initialization of children cannot be 'delayed'. Usually route resolvers are used to get asynchronous dependencies in components, but they often incorporate observables too for convenience, and I don't think that this approach plays well with what you're trying to do with `db` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. With promises, the concern was that I didn't want to return a promise to each the callers. I wanted to check if there was a way to initialize a service within a component with a parameter provided on the component itself.
Apparently it is not possible without promises and/or observables...

Comment: It depends on how the service is supposed to be used by children. But it should be noticed that promises are good for `async` functions, and observables can be found everywhere through A2. If you do async DB queries with asynchronously initialized DbService, does it really matter that it is async 'twice'?

Comment: Btw, this pattern was nicely implemented by Mongoose (MongoDB ORM). Even though `mongoose.connect(...)` is async, it internally chains initialization promise to other async methods, so `mongoose.connect(...); mongoose.find(...).then(...)` is the same thing as `mongoose.connect(...).then(() => mongoose.find(...)).then(...)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: "does it really matter that it is async 'twice'" Good point @estus thanks. It will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

In workspace component use @input db:string variable and set the db variable where you are using the workspace component.

for Ex:

```
<workspace [db]="/a/b/c"></workspace>


@Component({
  selector: 'workspace',
  template: `
    {{db}}
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input() db: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an explicit `init` method on your DbService, and then do this:

```html
<workspace [db]="a/b/c"></workspace>
```

```js
export class WorkspaceComponent{
  @Input() db;

  constructor(private dbService: DbService){
    dbService.init(db)
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't guarantee that dbService will be available for use by the sub components. Basically children components need dbService fully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the components change detection strategy to OnPush. What that basically does is that the change detection will only run when the inputs change. The next part is to hook any logic you want to run in the component into the `ngOnChanges()` method which will fire every time the component is hydrated via the input which you control so your db service will always be initialized with the correct path:

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class WorkspaceComponet
{
    @Input() db;

    constructor(private dbService: DbService)
    {
    }

    ngOnChanges()
    {
        this.dbService.init(this.db)
    }

}
```

Comment: how the children components will be notified about the async initialisation that is triggered by this.dbService.init(this.db)  ?